# Using jsPDF to render dynamic data on PDF template

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, pdf-generation, jspdf

Newbie here. I'm making an app that retrieves data from an API, makes some charts from these data (probably using d3.js) and then renders these charts and some dynamic text on a PDF template, generating a PDF doc that can then be downloaded by the user.

I'm wondering if jsPDF can be used to fill in dynamic data on a pre-existing PDF template. Most of the PDF document is static, and it's just a few dynamic charts that need to be added in, depending on what the user inputs.

Comment: I don't know jsPDF, but D3 seems like the wrong choice for chart generation in this case, since its strength is in interactive mapping between data and DOM nodes. It sounds like you just need to generate a chart image to place in the PDF.

Comment: You can take what you made in D3 (I assume you'll be writing SVG) and then plug it in to your PDF. jsPDF has a plugin called [svgToPDF](https://github.com/ahwolf/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.plugin.svgToPdf.js) so that might come in handy. I think dynamic is the wrong word to use here -- you should make it so that there's some sort of download button and when they click it, you save the SVG onto a PDF and simply give it to them.

Comment: All of what you ask can easily be done using XSL FO to generate the PDF, scraping the SVG from the application.

Answer (score 0):

All of what you ask can easily be done using XSL FO to generate the PDF, scraping the SVG from the application. Most XSL FO processors would also support stamping in the charts onto static PDFs or even generating the content of the pages dynamically.